# Some examples of "Clean topological spaces'

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

What is  an example of  a Hausdorff topological space $X$, not a singleton,  such that the ring $C(X)$ of all real (or complex) valued continuous functions on $X$ is a clean ring.

A clean ring is  a ring in which every element is  a sum of a unit and an idempotent.

Comment: This question was now [posted on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/238915/some-examples-of-clean-topological-spaces).